# Error while converting html entities to hieroglyphs/special symbols [python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, html-entities, html-encode

My program gets JSON string from webserver using `requests`. Then it converted to a dictionary with `json.loads()`. After that I write some elements from this dictionary in a loop to the file:

```
parsedJSON = json.loads(cleanJSON)

for i in range(len(parsedJSON['list'])):
            f.write(html.unescape(parsedJSON['list'][i][4]) + ' - ' +  html.unescape(parsedJSON['list'][i][3]) + '\n')
```

The problem is that JSON can contain japanese/chinese hieroglyphs and other special symbols. In JSON string I get they are stored as html entities (for example this string '`&# 12493;&# 12467;&# 12496;&# 12473;`' is ネコバス).

To convert html entities to a human-readable form, I use `html.unescape('someHTMLEntity')`. On my Debian 8 and some other linux systems it works perfect - hieroglyph codes are converted to actual hieroglyphs, etc. But on Windows (on 7, 8.1 and 10) I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 144, in <module>
    f.write(html.unescape(parsedJSON['list'][i][4]) + ' - ' +  html.unescape(par
sedJSON['list'][i][3]) + '\n')
  File "C:\Users\dangerous\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\encodin
gs\cp1251.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 12-15: c
haracter maps to <undefined>
```

The program crashes when the function `html.unescape('someHieroglyphCode')` is executed.

As I understand it's some Windows-specific encoding problem, but I can't understand what exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it explicitly using utf-8 encoding in open():

```
f = open('./dump', 'a', encoding='utf-8')
```